# Prevent toIsoString to change day

Tags: javascript, date

When I do this:

`new Date('4/7/2018').toISOString();`

I get: `"2018-04-06T22:00:00.000Z"`

How can I get an ISO string but without the date changing from 7 to 6? I basically want the same date, month and year.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Date strings do not have a timezone. Using the built-in parser for any format other than the one specified in ECMA-262 (a limited subset of ISO 8601) is implementation dependent and should not be used, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

A couple of options are to parse the string as UTC values and then use *toISOString* and remove the trailing Z, or you can just reformat the string, e.g.

```js
var s = '4/7/2018';

// Parse string in m/d/y format and return
// in ISO 8601 format
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[2],b[0]-1,b[1])).toISOString().slice(0,19);
}

console.log(parseDMY(s));

function reformatDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}; 
  return `${b[2]}-${z(b[0])}-${z(b[1])}T00:00:00`;
}

console.log(reformatDate(s));
```

But really, if you just have a date, it should be left as just a date, so:

```js
var s = '4/7/2018';

// Assume date is M/D/Y
function reformatDate(s) {
  var a = s.split(/\D/).map(n=>(n<10?'0':'')+n);
  return a[2]+'-'+a[0]+'-'+a[1];
}

console.log(reformatDate(s));
```

Comment: Rob, thanks. What do you think of this as a solution:
`var timezoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; new Date(new Date('4/7/2018') - timezoneOffset).toISOString()`

Comment: @HommerSmith—it's still using the built-in parser with an unsupported (by ECMA-262) format.

Answer (score 3):

Use `2018Z` in your year field:

```js
var res = new Date('4/7/2018Z').toISOString();
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Can you explain why is this happening and what is that Z?

Comment: Specifying `Z` will consider your local time zone and it will change the format without the reference time of the UTC. @HommerSmith

Comment: Dates do not have a timezone. The behaviour of *Date.parse* in this case is entirely implementation dependent and should not be relied on. Some browsers will return an invalid date, others will likely ignore the "Z".

Comment: @RobG what solution do you suggest?

Comment: Ok, if you want to add a solution, I will accept it.

Comment: I think I agree with Rob. Dates don't have a timezone, so it's weird that we add the 'Z' in the date. However, I will mark it as accepted for now, as it seems to be the best and working solution provided.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal—try it in Firefox or Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is to do with the locale of the machine (i.e you're on gmt+2 so 4/7/2018 at 00:00:00 is indeed 2018-04-06T22:00:00.000Z)

You could do `new Date('4/7/2018 GMT').toISOString();`